# How to search li contains text values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have list of letters. I would like to filter any contain values while user enter the text in textbox.

**Design :**

Search List :

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />

<ul>
  <li>Coffee1</li>
  <li>Coffee2</li>
  <li>Tea1</li>
  <li>Tea2</li>
  <li>Milk1</li>
  <li>Milk2</li>
</ul>
```

**E.g:**
If user entered values in textbox as `k1` means I would like to get and filtered only `Milk1 & Milk2`.

How to do it ?

Please help me solve.

Comment: Technically, `k1` will fetch `Milk1` only. It don't have any link with `Milk2`. Search should ignore that. If you still want it then you have to write your own algorithm for this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There are lots and lots of filter examples available in a web search and the jQuery api even has a selector`:contains()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you may filter the list elements. Any time the input change, hide all list elements, find only those that have the typed string and show them:

```
$('#txtSearch').on('input', function() {
     var that = this;
     $(this).next('ul').find('li').hide().filter(function() {
         return $(this).text().indexOf( that.value ) > -1;
     })
     .show();
});
```

```js
$('#txtSearch').on('input', function() {
     var that = this;
     $(this).next('ul').find('li').hide().filter(function() {
         return $(this).text().indexOf( that.value ) > -1;
     })
     .show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />

<ul>
  <li>Coffee1</li>
  <li>Coffee2</li>
  <li>Tea1</li>
  <li>Tea2</li>
  <li>Milk1</li>
  <li>Milk2</li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE**.
Using the `input` event catches even pasted input.

Ref: [`.filter( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: lot of thanks & thanks for the post.

Comment: I tried it's working fine but if i search as small letters that time value not filter. E.g. I tried 'Coffee1' to 'coffee1' that time value not filter. how to make case-insensitive. How to do it. Please help?

Comment: You would have to make it case-insensitive by using **return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf( that.value.toLowerCase()  ) > -1;**

Answer (score 0):

Using the :contains() selector, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aevf5tbb/)

relevant code:

```
$('#txtSearch').keyup(function(){
  $('li').hide();
  $('li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').show();
})
```

Also, if you want it to be case-insensitive, you can do as in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aevf5tbb/1/). In this fiddle we add a :Contains() selector as follows

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

And use that selector instead of the normal :contains() selector.

Comment: lot of thanks for the post.

Comment: @dhamodaran if it helped, please upvote/accept

Comment: Hi, I tried It's working fine. But i have little bit issue. That is if i have three list values. That value looks like 'TestNew1', 'testNew2', 'Testnew3'. I tried to type as 'T' that time i can see both list values. But i tried to type 'Te' that time i can't able to see 'testNew2' list. How to fix this issue.

Comment: So you want it to be case-insensitive?

Comment: @dhamodaran added a second fiddle in case you want it case-insensitive